# Trying to create a list for my react chart 2-js graph data using api list data & want to iterate different array object list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object, multidimensional-array

I have below api list data coming from backend, I want to iterate them in Javascript  & make arrayList[] for further use for creating  graph using react-chart2 js.

```
0:{problem: Array(28), release:"rs_21.2"}
1:{problem: Array(28), release:"rs_21.3"}
2:{problem: Array(28), release:"rs_21.5"} 
so on .......
```

Further, I want to iterate over "problem" which is Array[objects] having data like below:-

```
problem:Array(28)
 >0:{id:1234,originator:{firstName LastName},title:""}
 >1:{id:1235,originator:{firstName LastName},title:""} & so on..

  Below is my code to iterate the originator from problem, but unable to get the data 
   
    let problemList =[];

      result.problem.forEach(record => {
         problemList.push(problem.originator.firstName+''+problem.originator.lastName);
        }

  I'm not getting the orignator data, what i'm doing wrong in iterating, any help will be 
 appreciated
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `record.originator.firstName` instead of problem (same with all the others within the `forEach`), as `problem` points to your full collection instead of the specific object. That's why you have the declaration of the `record` variable in the `forEach`; it points to your specific object inside the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I got the originator List by iterating the record with following below code

```
  problemList.forEach(record => {
      record.forEach(data => {
         originatorList.push(data.originator.firstName+''+data.originator.lastName);
            })
         })
            console.log(originatorList); // gives the originatorList names
```